# MVC - Ajax - Inconsistency between Chrome and IE 9

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I have an MVC view where I am doing some paging of data, using the `PagedList` component. My JavaScript to support this looks as follows:

```
$(function () {

    var getPage = function () {
        var $a = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $a.attr("href"),
            type: "get"
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("data-ExchangeSite-target");
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            $(target).replaceWith(data);
        });

        return false;
    };

    $(".main-content").on("click", ".pagedList a", getPage);

});
```

My .cshtml file looks, in part, like this:

```
    @model ExchangeSite.Entities.BicycleSearchSeller

    <div id="itemList">

        <div class="pagedList" data-ExchangeSite-target="#itemList">
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model.BicycleSellerListingList, pageNumber => Url.Action("Index", new {pageNumber}),
            PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
        </div>
   ...
   ...
```

In IE9, this works perfectly. When I click on a specific page number, or the next/previous page, an asynch call is made to my controller to refresh the list of data ("itemList"). However, in Chrome, two calls are made to my controller. One is an Ajax call, the other is not. Can anyone tell me why, in Chrome, two calls are made to my controller? If you need to see more code, please let me know.

Comment: In your success callback you seem to have some `data: $("form").serialize(),` line which doesn't fit the picture. Why is this line terminated with a comma instead of a colon? Is this your real code? Which version of jQuery are you using? Could you show your full view code? Can you see some javascript errors in your Chrome console? I am unable to reproduce the problem. Other than the line I have mentioned earlier, the code you have posted seems fine.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Yes this is my actual code. The comma was a bug. Replacing it with a semicolon solved the problem. It seems IE wasn't bothered by this but Chrome was. Thank you. If you enter your comments as an answer, I'll vote you up and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some buggy line in your success callback:

```
data: $("form").serialize(),
```

It is terminated with a comma instead of semicolon. It also contains a colon after `data`. IE might be a little more tolerant towards broken javascript compared with Google Chrome.

Comment: Thank you. I'd also like to thank you for your active participation on SO, related to MVC. You have been a tremendous help to me.